# Nested looping of List in Velocity Template Engine?

Tags: java, templates, list, loops, velocity

I am want to iterate a loop withing a loop in the velocity template.I have list of objects for say states and in that state object there is a property called cities which is again a list.

```
public class State{
  public String stateName = "";
  public float stateArea = "";
  public List stateCities = "";
}



List<State> state = new ArrayList<State>();
```

Basically i want to iterate over this kind of structure in velocity template engine.I can get the normal properties like String and float but i am not able to iterate "stateCities" property.If any more details are required on this please let me know.

Thx
Sagar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried this myself, but does something like the following not work?

```
#foreach( $state in $states )
   $state.stateName
   $state.stateArea
   #foreach ($city in $state.stateCities)
       $city
   #end
#end
```

Comment: This doesn't work in my testing. I've verified that the "state" array contains rows but velocity insists on just printing out "$city" (or in my case "$row.issue" where I have a public member variable named "issue").